# Runtime error with net7.0-android application built by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, xamarin.android

I've a net7.0-android application (formerly Xamarin Android).
It runs correctly when built from Visual Studio 2022.
I've setup a Jenkins server with a simple checkout, test and build pipeline.
The pipeline succeed, but when I run the application, it crashes with the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Cannot create instance of type 'ZXing.Mobile.ZXingScannerFragment': no 
Java peer type found.
```

ZXing.Mobile referenced in the error is my porting to Net7 of [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile)
library.
This library is made available as nuget package served from a local directory.

Jenkins issues this command to build the apk:

`dotnet.exe build myProjectName.csproj -c:Release -f:net7.0-android`

If I execute the same command manually, surprisingly the resulting apk works correctly.
If I reference directly the library project from the app project, the apk works correctly too.

Can't figure out what's different between the same command (dotnet build) when executed by me vs when executed by Jenkins.